# sum together values in database column

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, sum

I am creating a web project in c# on asp.net. I am displaying data from a database on the webpage. I have a database table where a column (month) shows which month a customer made an order and another column with the stock id. Each month and stockid is shown numerous times as different customers make orders each month.  I would like to total the quantity of orders from the quantity column for each month of a specific stock. At the moment i can only display one of the quantities for each month when it loops but would like to count and display the total for each month.

```
    public static ArrayList GetActuals()
    {
        String strQuery = "Select * from Actual where Year = 2013";
        Recordset rs = DatabaseManager.GetRecordset("DB", strQuery);

        bool bFound;

        ArrayList Actuals = new ArrayList();
        while (rs != null && rs.Read())
        {
            Actual A = new Actual();
            A.strStockNo = rs.GetFieldValueString("Stock_No").Trim();
            A.nMonth = rs.GetFieldValueInt("Month");
            A.nYear = rs.GetFieldValueInt("Year");
            A.nCustomer = rs.GetFieldValueInt("Customer");
            A.nQuantity = (float)rs.GetFieldValueDouble("Quantity");
            Actuals.Add(A);

        }

        if (rs != null) rs.Close();
        return Actuals;

    }



    float LoadActuals(ArrayList actual, String strstock, int year, int month)
    {

        foreach (Actual a in actual)
        {

            if ((a.strStockNo == strstock) && (a.nYear == year) && (a.nMonth == month))
            {
                return a.nQuantity;
            }


        } return 0;
    }
```

Then when i display the quantity for each month....

```
            int Month;
            for (Month = 1; Month < 13; Month++)
            {

                    float totq = LoadActuals(Act, p.strStockNo, yr, Month);

                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Text = string.Format("{0}", totq);
             }
```

This only displays one totq for each month where as i want the total. How is this done?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Good for including a link explaining frustrations, but they're clearly new here so do try to be nice and constructive.

Comment: which database and you want this in your query or in your c# code?

Comment: In my c# code.  I have an arraylist which stores the results from the query but when displaying them on the webpage under the specific colums i.e jan, feb, mar... it only shows one result i want to show a total of the values for each month?

Comment: @newbie1 instead of describing your code, post some minimal, self-contained version of it and ask a specific question.

Comment: you need to actually show what your existing code looks like for others to be able to effectively help you `newbie1`

Comment: I changed it best i could...

Comment: @Clint, the link is self-explanatory. Author nicely describes what (and why) to do when you're asking a question online and it's a must-read for every programmer.

Answer (score 0):

So many questions but... quickly.

```
float LoadActuals(ArrayList actual, String strstock, int year, int month)
{
    float quantity = 0;
    foreach (Actual a in actual)
    {
        if ((a.strStockNo == strstock) && (a.nYear == year) && (a.nMonth == month))
        {
            quantity += a.nQuantity;
        }
    }
    return quantity;
}
```